# True/False- Does the limit exist?

Tags: real-analysis

True or False: Suppose that $f$ is bounded. Suppose that $f$ is not continuous at $x$=$a$. Then $\lim_{x\to\ a} f(x)$ exists but is not equal to $f(a)$.

I want to say false because all we know is that it is bounded and not continuous at one point and not all bounded sequences have limits.

Comment: See $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$, with $f(0)=3$.

Comment: For a more extreme example, let $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is bounded but $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ fails to exist anywhere.

Comment: FYI, it seems to me the question would be more interesting if existence of one-sided limits replaces existence of the limit. The same examples posted still work, but not not the very elementary piece-wise defined functions one sees in precalculus (examples I suspect the author of the question would want to exclude).

Comment: All these nice counterexamples seem beside the point to me: why on earth _should_ $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exist? What does the boundedness of $f$ have to do with anything? _Any_ function (bounded, if you like) that doesn't tend to a limit at $x=a$ would be a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

False : consider $"\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\sin(\frac{1}{x})",$ with $f(0)$ equals what you want.